# How to represent checkin / checkout in a REST system?

Tags: rest

I've been wrestling with the problem of representing a checkout / checkin system via a REST api.

To give you a small example our system handles nodes and we need a way for one user to be able to lock this node and then make changes to it and then commit it.

So I was thinking something like

- `/nodeId` (this is the base location for a node and provides an up to date checked in revision read only view of the node)
- `/nodeId/edited` (posting to here creates an edited version of the doc this is checkout, gettting gets the edited version, and putting makes a change)

Now I want to represent checkin, im tempted to say that POSTing to `/nodeId/edited` again will commit the edited document but then we are, giving post two distinct meanings. I could create another checkin endpoint but that seems messy? Another alternative is having a POST to /nodeId which creates the edited version but again this seems confused.

Answer (score 2):

To lock/checkout a Resource, `POST` to `/nodeId`  with the partial document `{"locked":"true"}`. The server must handle Resource state and check if the Resource can be locked etc. The server could answer `204 No Content` if the lock suceeded and `409 Conflict` if the lock was not possible.

To unlock/checkin the locked Resource, `POST` to `/nodeId` with the partial document `{"locked":"false", "someKey":"someValue", ...}`. The server must handle Resource state, check if the Resource is locked, and update it usinng the `POST`ed data. Again, the server could answer `204 No Content` if the unlock suceeded and `409 Conflict` if not.

**Edit:** added possible HTTP status codes.

**Edit 2:** There is no "endpoint" in REST like in SOAP. You manipulate Resources, you don't call methods.

Comment: Hi Tichodroma, thanks for your answer. This is also a method I considered although this approach does not seem to be the restful approach to me. I was under the impression that the verbs POST,PUT,GET and DELETE should map to add, edit, retrieve and delete operations respectively. In your example post is not corresponding to addition of a node, in fact I would say that your example is essentially an RPC, you are sending some data to that identifies a method to invoke and not treating /nodeId as a resource. Please let me know if you think my understanding is incorrect. Thanks Piers

Comment: My idea is not RPC but something called a partial update: using POST against the Resource with only a partial represenation (here: JSON) that includes only those properties of the Resource that should be changed. To add a *new* Resource, you would POST against some collection like `/nodes`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Tichodroma, its starting to make a bit more sense. One thing though, why are you using POST and not PUT ? My understanding is that POST should be used for creating a resource and PUT for updating? Thanks Piers

Comment: Dude?? What's crackin, ur so close to getting this answer, just need to know about POST and PUT?? Easy

Comment: You are right. PUT would be better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest